# Which are the type constructors in C++?

Tags: c++

In many programming languages, there are **ways to define new types out of the built ins**.

What are the **ways this can be done in C++ ?**

Let me cross out the obvious ones :

- pointers  : applying `*` to type gives a new type `pointer to type`
- arrays    : you can make an array of built in types and this defines a new type
- templates : you can wrap any built in type `T` in a class template `my_class<T>` defining a new type

Comment: See section 3.9.2 [basic.compound] of the C++ standard. (Free draft standard available at https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard)

Comment: Struct, combines a set of types.

Comment: Union, overlays a set of types.

Comment: I'm wondering the same dude. Probably your question has been misinterpreted.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 types of modifiers on the declarator level:

- Pointer to type/reference to type;
- Array of types elements;
- Function, returning type;

You can combine these modifiers although with certain restrictions. Modifier `const` is not creating a new data type. I it restricts the set of applicable operations.

There are 2 things on the class level:

- Derived Class;
- Template Specialization;

Once again, these are modifiers of something already existing. Unions and struct create new objects, they are not modifying their containing fields.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici), the related Standard quote is in 3.9.2.

This paragraph describes the creation of **compound types**

> Compound types can be constructed n the following ways
>
> — arrays of objects of a given type, 8.3.4;
>
> — functions , which have parameters of given types and return void or references or objects of a given type, 8.3.5;
>
> — pointers to void or objects or functions (including static members of classes) of a given type, 8.3.1;
>
> — references to objects or functions of a given type, 8.3.2. There are two types of references:
>
> — lvalue reference
>
> — rvalue reference
>
> — classes containing a sequence of objects of various types (Clause 9), a set of types, enumerations and functions for manipulating these objects (9.3), and a set of restrictions on the access to these entities (Clause 11);
>
> — unions, which are classes capable of containing objects of different types at different times, 9.5;
>
> — enumerations, which comprise a set of named constant values. Each distinct enumeration constitutes a different enumerated type, 7.2;
>
> — pointers to non-static class members, which identify members of a given type within objects of a given class, 8.3.3.